# Should my navigation bar start as transparent then become opaque on scroll?

Tags: interface-design, mobile, android, ios, user-experience

Android has this UI behaviour: The navigation bar is transparent at first, with only the back button. But as the screen is scrolled up, the navigation bar becomes opaque, and the title fades in (on translate to position).

iOS has a different native behaviour. The navigation bar is shown as opaque/translucent at first. At the screen is scrolled up, the navigation bar could auto hide.

As an iOS designer, which behaviour should I stick to? Is it okay to adopt an Android behaviour?

My use case is a screen browsing a movie details - trailer, synopsis, showtimes, etc.

Comment: It's actually really hard to overwrite default scroll bar behaviour. So if you don't really have to I'd stay away from modifying that.

Comment: @PieBie that is a horrible guidance to go on. Following the path of least friction just lands you at the bottom of the design barrel. Many great design principles and trends can ONLY be implemented by going beyond what's out of the box. And in the current age of immersive/full-screen apps – YES, you absolutely should make the nav bar transparent, drive your content full-screen, and find a smooth way of fading it in as needed as the user scrolls. Your devs will need to spend a full day battling the framework – your users will enjoy it for years.

Comment: Welcome to "battling the framework". Nicely said.

Comment: @Marchy: I did not say to follow the path of least friction or be lazy. I have seen (and been) developers battling frameworks because the designer thought it would be really cool to have their own interaction elements. Result: a form that looked great but was nigh unusable. Users are used to a certain behaviour on their machines. If you are going to change that, you'd better be damn sure the behaviour is logical and very clear. And if you are uncertain of your capabilities or if it's a good idea, it's probably best to stick with what your users know.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Human Interface Guidelines (HIG) are as the last word says, GUIDELINES.

You're entirely welcome to change everything to any way of doing things you like. They don't really care, and truly welcome better ways of doing things.

Take a look at the many synth and music apps on iPad. They're so far from the HIG you can't recognise them as being part of any design era. Yet they're premium products and people love using them daily, and Apple approves them.

Examples:

Here's Waldorf ignoring the no branding "guideline", and MANY other aspects of the HIG, to great effect:

[image: Waldorf ignoring the "no app branding rule"]

One of the most popular todo list apps completely eschews any correlation to the HIG:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clear-tasks-reminders-to-do/id493136154?mt=8

[image]

Comment: That's true. But so far for my movie app, we follow the guideline to have a consistent native feel. I appreciate the guidelines because it helps user using a consistent UI. In my scenario, I don't see the Android way being as useful -- why would I want to see the nav bar when I scroll?

Comment: There are MANY iOS apps that continue to show the nav bar during scrolling. Don't worry about consistency, don't over think it. If it works, if it's needed, if it's consistent to YOUR app, and it's discernible and determinable by the user, it's consistent enough.